# Hiding a crack in glass

Tags: repair, crack, glass

From time to time I'll find a crack in some glass item I own where the crack isn't a structural issue, but is only a visual issue. The crack is visible because of the air in the crack causing a sudden change in the refractive index. I'm assuming there are no good ways to truly fix such a crack, but I'd like to make it less visible.

The obvious approach would be to drop on some water or oil that would fill the crack; this should stop the sudden refractive index change and hide the crack. But, this would only be temporary, as the water (and even the oil) would eventually evaporate or migrate away from the crack.

Are there any good, permanent ways to hide a crack in glass?

Comment: Could you give some example objects and crack sizes? I think trying to fix a hairline in a glass bunny trinket may be different than a glass top coffee table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are products which claim to hide cracks on windshields by injecting an adhesive with similar refractive index. I have no idea whether they work in that application, and your glass objects may have different optical properties, so there is no promise that this won't make matters worse rather than better.

Comment: You've just reminded me that I bought one of those windshield repair kits with the intention of hiding a small crack across the corner of a large window in my house. I'll try to remember to use it this weekend & report the results ...

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with a drop of Krazy Glue to hopefully minimize the visual & to support the structure so the crack doesn't increase. Water drip both sides first, if they're full breach, to determine where to apply the glue. Of course, tape around the crack or instantly wipe excess glue away.